# why ImageIO.write returns 0 in writing JPEG 2000 images?

Tags: java, image

How can I know why imageIO.write was not able to write the image successfully? it returns false when I try to write a jpeg2000 image. I am using JDK6 and JRE6 that have JAI implicit. I really appreciate your helps.

Thank you.

Comment: `0`? Don't you mean `false`? As per its [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write%28java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29) it returns a `boolean`.

Comment: yes, sorry for the mistake. it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Javadoc, it will return `false` if no appropriate writer is found.  Try calling `ImageIO.getWriterFormatNames()` to see which formats are accepted.